# array_filter only works with the first array in a given nested associative array on the front-end

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-filter

I have an associative array which is essentially the following:

```
$my_users = array (
   array(
     'customers_id' => 123,
     'customers_name' => 'Jewelry By Me'
   ),
   array(
     'customers_id' => 321,
     'customers_name' => 'Mary Kay'
   )
)
```

And a small conditional to search this array for a specific customer name:

```
if($request->param('company_name')) {
  $input = "/".$request->param('company_name')."/";
  $users = array_filter($my_users, function($k, $v) use ($input) {
    if (preg_match($input, $k['customers_company'], $matches)) {
      return $matches;
    }
  }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
}
```

If I pass in a value, say, "Jewe", it will correctly return the array where the company_name is "Jewelry By Me" to my front end table.

However, if I pass in a value like "Mar" or even "Mary", it does not return any rows to my front end table.

var_dumping $matches for each case reveals the following:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "Jewe" }
array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "Mar" }
```

var_dumping $users correctly shows the data I'm looking for.

Similarly my other array_filter function which has no regex simply takes in the customers_id and is supposed to return the row where the customers_id = passed_in_customers_id_param. This again, works only on Jewelry By Me but not on Mary Kay.

To reiterate, var_dumping does reveal the correct data, but on the front end on my table only the data associated with Jewelry By Me is displayed.

I'm at a loss to explain this behavior and fix it.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no `customers_company` key in your arrays. Did you mean `customers_name`?

Comment: You're naming the arguments to the callback confusingly. It should be `$v, $k`.

Comment: Why are you using `preg_match()` instead of `strpos()`? Can the parameter really be a regular expression?

Comment: If `var_dump($users)` shows the correct result, then the problem isn't with this code, it's with the code that returns it to the front end, or the client code that displays it.